Is there any way to mapping the Google OAuth2.0 ID and DB in Boot 3?
It was my first time, so I didn't know about the structure of OAuth.
Before I made a system of Google OAuth Login, I had made my own Register form and some functions. In the Form, there are many not null fields which the Google OAuth Login doesn't include, and many functions are using the fields.
So, I made the process, after Google OAuth Login successes, the user fills the Register form and the form saves in DB with providerId. I thought if I used saved data, there were a way to combine OAuth and the DB right after users logged in by OAuth automatically during login. Therefore, like exsisting Login function, I thought OAuth could be adjusted in funtions without any additional code.
Unfortunately, it seems the exsiting Login and OAuth Login operate completely separately.  I didn't find the way to pack them and now I am here to ask.
I am so scared to add code for OAuth Login in all functions. Now, I almost gave up and really considered the cheating ,for example, after post the Form, redirectly logged out and logged thorough My Own Login.
Is there any good Idea?
